# NSWorkSpace SetIcon not Refreshing

Tags: macos, cocoa, finder, nsworkspace

I'm using NSWorkSpace `setIcon:forFile:options:` on a folder.

However, while the API returns success(true) every time the api is utilized, sometimes the Icon is not updated on the folder.

I've noticed creating a new file inside of the folder will trigger the icon to reappear, which leads me to believe that Finder needs to refresh the folder.

Is there a way to determine when the Icon has actually been set, and the folder needs to be refresh? And is there a way to refresh the folder without creating & deleting a file quickly?

Comment: I did some research here: [GitHubGIST :: Noitidart / _ff-addon-snippet-SetIconForFile.js](https://gist.github.com/Noitidart/9dbb37af01f4939cbcca) you can pass `nil` instead of the `icon` and it will revert the image to what the icon is supposed to be by default based on the `plist.info` and images in `/Contents/Resources/`. There are some caveats, like you have to set to something first with this function, then you can pass `nil` and it will revert. Can you please verify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out there is a function to help notify Finder of the file change.

NSWorkSpace `noteFileSystemChanged` does this.

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsworkspace/1579268-notefilesystemchanged

However, it does not seem to work for folder icon changes.

Seems like the only option is to create/delete a file.

Comment: Does create/delete a file work for 10.9? i tried but its not refreshing. i have blah.app file on my desktops, i went into it contents/resources/appicon.icns and replaced it with another icon also named appicon.icns but the icon isnt taking :(

Comment: It does indeed work for 10.9
Are you using the SetIcon API? It seems like you are replacing a file but not calling anything - system might not know to use the new file, potentially due to caching.

Comment: Thanks @Edo can you please watch my screencast, it doesnt seem to work for me. I create file with NSFileManager createFileAtPath and then delete it with removeItemAtPath: [Youtube :: Demo of Create-Remove File Not Updating Icon](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WcAxUCWB05g) I have no idea why it wont force my appbundle to refresh to the icon i replaced it with.

Comment: Ah you are right I had to just make the file INSIDE the app bundle. My app bundle is `/Users/noi/Desktop/default profile.app` after replacing the icon i had to create a file at path `/Users/noi/Desktop/default profile.app/ctypes make.js` and it updated. So it looks like `createFile` is all that we need to do, are you sure you need to run `[NSWorkSpace SetIcon:forFile:options]` at all?